# How to define the Sobolev quotient space $H^s(Γ)/{\mathbb R}$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, differential-calculus, quotient-space

Let $\Gamma$ be the boundary of a Lipschitz domain $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^3$. Denote by $H^s(\Gamma)$ the usual scalar Sobolev space for $s\in\mathbb R$. I want to know the definition of the quotient space $H^s(\Gamma)/\mathbb R$ used in the paper "Décomposition de H-1/2div (Γ) et nature de l'opérateur de Steklov-Poincaré du problème extérieur de l'étectromagnétisme" by Armel de la Bourdonnaye. Does it consist of all functions of the form $u+c$ where $u\in H^s(\Gamma)$ and $c\in\mathbb R$?

Comment: Exactly, with the associated quotient structure, and quotient norms.